# Did we ever see the deck 9 windows of the Enterprise-D from the inside?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

One of the most recognizable locations on the Enterprise-D is Ten Forward, whose windows are visibly curved, which is easily noticeable from both inside and out. But what about the windows on deck 9, the ones that look like an inverted copy of Ten Forward's windows? Do we ever see those from the inside? (Or any other deck 10 windows for that matter.)

Officers' quarters are often said to be located on deck 9, however they invariably are shown with straight, slanted windows like on decks 8 and above.

Comment: @Valorum: That picture does not support the claim (but rather the counter-argument brought forward by the OP); the [list of decks/rooms on MA kind of does](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy_class_decks), though. Now, it would be somewhat interesting to know whether that was nailed down before the Ten Forward set was introduced in season 2, whereby the decision was made that the formerly planned observation deck around the rim with windows near the ceiling and near the floor was actually two decks.

Comment: Maybe the artificial gravity on that deck is the other way up?

Comment: Flip flopping gravity from deck to deck would make using emergency ladders difficult

Comment: And make falling down a turbolift shaft significantly more fun! Imagine if Picard and his kid crew spent the whole of Disaster just bouncing up and down that turboshaft as they sang Frère Jacques.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, the saucer section deck numbering goes from [Deck 1 (e.g. the Bridge at the very top of the ship) down to deck 18 at the bottom](https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints/whitefire-enterprise-ncc-1701d/whitefire-enterprise-ncc-1701d-sheet-4.jpg), so we'd expect the see any rooms on Decks 1-10 with windows sloping *forward* and any rooms on decks 11-18 with windows sloping in different directions, primarily backwards.

We see a bunch of ship's quarters from Deck 8 and Deck 9 in the show. All of them have the windows sloping *forward* from the top rather than upside down, which is as it should be.

**Jenna D'Sora quarters** (Deck 8) - *TNG: In Theory*
[image]

**Riker's quarters** (Deck 8) - *TNG: Schisms*
[image]

**Troi's quarters** (deck 8) - *TNG: The Price*
[image]

**Picard's quarters** (Deck 9) - *TNG: The Perfect Mate*
[image]

That being said, we also see some rooms on decks 11-18 and their windows also slope forward. No in-universe explanation for this is given. In reality, of course, the reason is that these are simply the usual "quarters" set being repeatedly redressed.

**Guest quarters** (Deck 16) - *TNG: Violations*
[image]

**Crew quarters** (Deck 17) - *TNG: The Next Phase*
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Enterprise saucer  from the outside you can see that the majority of rooms with windows are on the upper side of the saucer.   There are five outer rings with lots of windows, two inner rings with fewer windows, and the bridge.   They all have the window sloping top-in bottom-out.

The underside of the saucer has only two rings of windows, and they are smaller rings than the topside.  And they probably aren't crew quarters.

[image]

The engineering section has about 2/3 windows on top, 1/3 underneath.